# Custom user authorization based with roles in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have created a custom authentication and authorisation for my users.The problem I am facing is how to get mvc to check that role from inside my users table matches the [Authorize(Role)] on my controller so as to set httpauthorised to true.Below is my customauthorise class.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorDetails"] = "You must be logged in to access this page";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/User/Login");
            return;
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            using (var db = new GManagerDBEntities())
            {
                var authorizedRoles = (from u in db.Users
                                       where u.Username == filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
                                       select u.Role).FirstOrDefault();
                Roles = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles) ? authorizedRoles.ToString() : Roles;
            }
        }

        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorDetails"] = "You do nat have necessary rights to access this page";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/User/Login");
            return;
        }

    }
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params object[] roles)
    {
        if (roles.Any(r => r.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Enum)))
            throw new ArgumentException("roles");

        this.Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(r => Enum.GetName(r.GetType(), r)));
    }
}
```

below is my controller with decoration

```
 [CustomAuthorize(Role.Administrator)]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateEmployees()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and my enum for role

```
public enum Role
{
    Administrator = 1,
    UserWithPrivileges = 2,
    User = 3,
}
```

and model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Username:")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
}
```

see pastie for clear view [pastie](http://pastie.org/9509756#1,4)

links I have viewed in trying to solve this among others but I cant seem to piece it together[MVC 3 Authorize custom roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658933/mvc-3-authorize-custom-roles)
http://forums.asp.net/p/1573254/3948388.aspx

[Customized authorization attribute in MVC 4 with Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942042/customized-authorization-attribute-in-mvc-4-with-roles)

Comment: take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Comment: Am hoping to use one single table and role as an integer but if all fails will just create a roles table and implement your suggestion @VikasRana

Comment: I tried changing it according to your link to this http://pastie.org/9510205 still no luck

Comment: Finally managed I hadnt put the ' protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)' method in global.asax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the link shared by @VikasRana http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

I got rid of my enum Role and my method

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params object[] roles)
    { ...}
```

I then changed Role in my model to be a string e.g. User.Role="Admin" instead of int.
In my onAuthorization method I changed it to:

```
` public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorDetails"] = "You must be logged in to access this page";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/User/Login");
            return;
        }
        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorDetails"] = "You don't have access rights to this page";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/User/Login");
            return;
        }
        }
```

and in my global.asax added this.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true && Request.IsAuthenticated== true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //let us take out the username now                
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string roles = string.Empty;

                    using (GManagerDBEntities db = new GManagerDBEntities())
                    {
                        User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

                        roles = user.Role;
                    }
                    //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie
                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //something went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above method is not ideal though.It gets run for every simple page request about 3 times or more.

**So here is solution 2:better solution**
Implement a *custom role provider* since we are already using custom role implementation.Simply follow this linkhttp://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gotalove for this method in Global.asax. Here is some more help for anyone trying to do a custom  Forms Authentication (FormsAuthentication, FormsAuthenticationTicket) using entity framework.

Login Controller
SetAuthTicket

```
protected void GetRoles(int UserID)
    {
        var db = new ResearchSurveysEntities();
        string[] getRoles = { };
        try
        {
            var query =

                from p in db.UserProfiles
                join i in db.webpages_UsersInRoles on p.UserId equals i.UserId
                join r in db.webpages_Roles on i.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                where p.UserId == UserID
                select new { p.UserId, r.RoleName };

            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {

                List<string> gRoles = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    gRoles.Add(item.RoleName);
                }
                getRoles = gRoles.ToArray();
            }
            roles = String.Join("|", getRoles);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebUtilities wu = new WebUtilities();

            wu.NotifyWebmaster(ex.ToString(), "Get roles for AdminUserID: " + UserID.ToString(), string.Empty, "Login Error");


        }
        finally
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

WebConfig

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Global.asax (From above example)

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie == null || authCookie.Value == "")
            return;

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket;
        try
        {
            authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }

        // retrieve roles from UserData
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split('|');

        if (Context.User != null)
            Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
    }
```